# Java logging: is it log or logger?

Tags: java, logging, naming-conventions, slf4j

Every now and then I run across code that looks like this:

```
private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

Let's assume this is an [`slf4j`](http://www.slf4j.org/) logger object. If one uses [Apache Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/%E2%80%8E) even the class will be called `Log` rather than `Logger`.

I've been contemplating this issue a little and have listed a few pros/cons with the two options below:

**Reasons for using `logger` instead of `log`**

1. **Purpose**: It is a writer of logs, not the log itself.
2. **Misleading**: `log` is an inherently misleading name, since the log cannot be read from.

**Reasons for using `log` instead of `logger`**

1. **Method invocation readability**: The methods available on a Logger are typically named `info()`, `error()` et cetera. As such, `log.error()` becomes something akin to a command spoken out loud as in "log this error", whereas `logger.error()` looks more like it would be reporting an error on the logger itself, not to mention what `logger.debug()` sounds like.

So, now the question. Is there perhaps even a third option for naming that pesky Logger? What do you use in your projects, and why?

Comment: `log` is half as long, that's a killer argument for me. Anyway, definitely not a contructive question.

Comment: Not a constructive question.

Comment: Actually I think it's a fair question, about coding style. My opinion: use `log` of, if static, `LOG`.

Comment: It's a good question about coding style.

Comment: @vikingsteve You see, you said "my opinion" => *not constructive*.

Comment: The Logger is usually the most ubiquitous object in any mature Java project, and as such, I believe it's reasonable to consider it's impact from a code style point of view. Or are coding style questions always out of bounds on SO? I was not under that impression.

Comment: Naming conventions are important and must be consistent across a project. The most important is to not mix "log" "logger" or even "LOG". I've got 10000 classes to maintain and the last thing I wan't to ask to myself when editing a class is "how is it named here?". It's not opinion, it's clean code.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there perhaps even a third option for naming that pesky Logger?

You can call it anything you like.  Even `lumberjack`, if it makes you feel happy<sup>1</sup>.

> What do you use in your projects, and why?

I use the class name as given by the logging framework that I'm currently using.  These days, I tend the SLF4J logging facade library so that people who might reuse my code are not hampered by my choice of logging.

I tend to use `log` as the name of the instance variable, or `LOG` if it is a `static final`.  Why?  Because 1) it is conventional and 2) it is fewer characters.  Either way, the reader will quickly learn the convention I use in my code.

I do agree that it is important to be consistent across each codebase that you work on.  But I don't think that your boss is going to approve your overtime to fix inconsistent naming of your loggers across 10,000 files.  Nor do I think your co-workers would appreciate having to code-review the changes. It is not *that* important.

---

<sub>1 - and that just about sums up my opinion of this question ...</sub>